# sql: select rows which have the same column value in another column with a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

example table:

```
id | value
----------
1  | abc
1  | cb3
1  | dsf
2  | sss
2  | d3
```

So if the input is "cb3" I want to get all rows with id 1, if the input is "sss" I want to get all rows with id 2. Can this be done with one query instead of two ? (first query is find id and second query bring rows for found id). Also, would a one query approach be faster ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From the word `input`, do you need a stored procedure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE my_table 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id 
         FROM TABLE my_table 
         WHERE value = input
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, where you replace `'sss'` with the value you are searching for:

```
select * from table t1
where t1.id in (select id from table t2 where value = 'sss')
```

Note that `value` seems not to be a key, such that you might get two different groups of ids in your result. That's also the reason why I proposed an `t1.id IN (select id ...` rather than an `t1.id = (select id ...`.

Comment: May I ask why t1 and t2? just a typo ?

Comment: Not a typo; Its just common practice to use aliases when using the same table more than once in the same query. In this case its not relevant as the queries are not correlated. But in many cases one can get weird behaviour because an attribute actually refers to a different context than one would mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using `inner join` also.

```
SELECT S.* 
FROM dataset AS S 
INNER JOIN dataset AS T 
ON S.id = T.id 
WHERE T.value = 'cb3';
```